# how to create two ajax paginations on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I create two separate ajax paginations on the same page using 'will_paginate' gem ?

I created two paginations according to rails casts screen cast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax. But it didnt seem to work well.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you have already solved the thing, but the whole point with multiple paginations on page is to use:

```
will_paginate @companies, :param_name => :companies_page, .....options
```

you can find it in the wiki on github also: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki

hope this helps somebody

Comment: then in controller it looks like:
@companies = Company.all.paginate(page: params[:companies_page], per_page: 20)

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari is more popular solution, you can use it with different objects, see the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari)

Comment: I also can use will_paginate with different objects. what i need is multiple ajax pginations on the same page.

Comment: How much object do you have to paginate? I'm using [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) to handle 1000+ records as well. It's javascript based solution will really fast pagination.

Comment: two objects. do you use datatables with ruby on rails?

Comment: yes, we have 2 webprojects use the Datatables. 2 benefits: 1) server generate the data only at once, 2) find, sorting, pagination is on client site by javascript. I did an [example of Github](https://gist.github.com/1087531) for you